# Maven dependency to source project (explode)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have two separate projects (ejb,web) , completely separate.
The problem is I want to add ejb project to web dependency by maven but I am looking for a explode dependency not jar, so when I compile ejb project the changes are effected in web project immediately.

If I want to use regular repository/dependency(jar) I should run mvn install after each change and it gonna be slow for developers and I don't want it.

Is there any solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Most advanced IDEs with Maven integration will be able to instantly update references in any dependent projects for a multi-module Maven project. However you'll still have to make sure you've run `mvn install` on all projects (or a parent project) before deploying.

Comment: I am looking if it is possible to handle with maven pom instead of IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven only allows to depend on a project's artifacts.

Exploded dependencies are not permitted: you can't store them in a repository, you need to zip/package them first. Maven emphasizes build consistency over speed and developer convenience, so features like incremental builds, unrolled dependencies or runtime code replacement are not available with standard maven.

However, other tools and IDE cheat by using unrolled dependencies when they can - for instance m2e (Eclipse's maven integration) uses the unrolled version of a project when it's opened in the workspace. But those tools are built on top (and around) maven.